# Invalid App ID: APP_ID, connect to facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I'm trying connect to facebook with code from this post[OmniAuth: Overview](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview)

My app run normally but when i connect to face book i have this error:

[image]

And my link to facebook:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=email&state=2576839c19b169d8be1dd4921a35aaa3d1f146946fdcc923
```

I'm using devise to connect

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

my gemfile

```
gem 'daemons', '~> 1.1.9'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0.2'

group :development do
  gem 'webrick', '~> 1.3.1'
end
```

Please help me to fix that :)

Comment: You are clearly not passing actual application ID anywhere, are you? See in your link: `?client_id=APP_ID&`, error clearly states that you passed literal string `APP_ID`.

Comment: Yeah! i should create app id in facebook. Thank you! can you tell me how to put app id into my app, here is my devise:
 `config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET"`